# Images with certain path types will not display in my webgl app

Tags: image, server

I have a webgl application and quite a bunch of images. It has, however, come to my attention that images with given paths do not get recognized and hence are not used as textures in this application while others work just fine.

for example images with paths like:

`assets/my_app/images/products/775/882/gHI1%201%200%20007%205NR%20H00968%2001b.jpg`

are not recognized, but whats worse is that I get no error whatsoever, except the fact that where a texture is supposed to be, I get none.

however paths like this works fine:

`assets/my_app/images/products/1/1/10_58_1458220717_exnurfqolcmsbpgajizdhkywt.jpg`

I really need the first kind of path to work as well because most of the images I am using are saved this way.

How best can I solve this issue. I have got quite a number of images. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @gman, thats not the issue.

Comment: what does the network tab in chrome show for each image? In particular under "headers"

Comment: Under the general tab: 

`Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8887/assets/my_app/images/products/1/1/10_58_1458220717_exnurfqolcmsbpgajizdhkywt.jpg
  Request Method: GET
 Status Code: 200 OK
 Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8887
 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
`
Response Headers: 
`accept-ranges: bytes
connection: keep-alive
 content-length: 105248
 content-type: image/jpeg`
This is for the successful one.

Comment: for the unsuccessful request: Under the general tab: 
`Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8887/assets/my_app/images/products/775/882/KI1%201%200%20007%205NR%20H00968%2001b.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8887
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Response Headers:
`accept-ranges: bytes
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 85
content-type: image/jpeg`

Comment: that response is from your server. it's telling you the path is wrong or at least according to the server there is no such file.

Comment: mhm. I see. but it is there. Indeed I followed the full path and the image is there as well. Why isnt the server able to pick this up? How can I resolve it?

Comment: that depends on your server. What server software are you using? Also just double checking, the path on the hard drive is `assets/my_app/images/products/775/882/KI1 1 0 007 5NR H00968 01b.jpg` (there is a **single space** between each of `1`, `1`, `0`, `007`, `5NR`, `H00968`, `01b.jpg`

Comment: No. Actually there are `%20`s in the image name. For test and all I am using Web Server for Chrome 0.4.8. But I plan to deploy it soon on an apache based webserver, So if possible let the solution target that please. I can do the remaining debugging on the server.

Comment: If there are `%` in the name on the hard drive you probably need to use '%25' everywhere there is a percent as in `http://127.0.0.1:8887/assets/my_app/images/products/775/882/KI1%25201%25200%2520007%25205NR%2520H00968%252001b.jpg` or use `encodeURI` to do it for you. `%` has a special mean in URLs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @gman thanks. that worked - atleast locally ). will try it later online. Sorry for the tardy reply was a bit ill. Can you convert it an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @gman can u make that an answer so that I accept it. It worked. I had it modified pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are actually `%` symbols in the filenames then you need to escape them by replacing `%` with `%25` in the url otherwise the server will read `%20` as a space so for a url of `KI1%20I` the server will look for `KI1 I` not `KI1%20I`